# Unknown instrument named in "Ondine et le pêcheur" by Paul Dukas

Tags: instruments, orchestration

[image: Ondine et le pêcheur by Paul Dukas]
([Image source](https://www.themorgan.org/music/manuscript/114446))

What is the instrument's name, I've searched it but I can't find it. It's in the score of *Ondine et le pêcheur* by Paul Dukas (c. 1884, unpublished).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Cor en fa" = Horn in F.

This is confirmed in the below recording. The link is timed to 27s, where the horns can be heard clearly.

---

Note: The seeming "z" (that is, "Coz en fa") is a script "r" missing its leading line. A similar "r" can be found in the "Contrabass" designation.

[image: "Contrabass" in Dukas's handwriting from the bottom of the first page of the "Ondine" score]

Comment: the 'z' shaped character is a old style cursive 'r'

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Well that explains a lot! Fascinating. How would I look something like that up? I tried some naive Google searches, but couldn't find anything except that R started out as a Phoenician character.

Comment: @Aaron well, I couldn't find a reliable source for that, but I know that manuscript/cursive R is often written similarly to that (with a very small, if not missing, leading line). Try searching Google Images with the "letter r cursive lowercase" query.

Comment: image search "cursive r"

Comment: @musicamante I see it now. The missing leading line was what I needed. Now it's clearly an "r".

Comment: @Aaron I'd also add the fact, from experience, that ***most*** of french manuscript scores are a nightmare of music reading. Not only they often wrote the crotchet rest *very similar* to a quaver one (a "Z"), but I also found lots of unbelievable notation. I still remember an *acciaccatura* written ***after*** the real note.

Comment: FWIW the word is "Contrebasses," the French plural, not "Contrabass," so the handwriting is rather less idiosyncratic than it might seem.  (Also, every letter started out as a Phoenician character.)